# error when install zabbix server on centos

Tags: centos, installation, zabbix

I install zabbix server on centos, I started service.  I get the following error when loading http://server_ip/zabbix:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /zabbix on this server.

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: You have omitted a lot of useful information, like which version of CentOS, how exactly did you install Zabbix.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am fixed. because I wrong when conf apache